# open-telemetry new link creates second ghost link

Tags: java, open-telemetry

We're using open-telemetry for Java version 1.36.0 and we're creating a new Span (using SpanBuilder) and adding a single link to a related span. That just one link was added via the API is verified by some logging. The link creation works and we get the link to the related traceId and spanId. We also get a link to the current traceId with a spanId of all 0's.

Expected:

trace (id=1)

- span (id=15)

  - link (related - traceId=2, spanId = 20)

Actual:

trace (id=1)

- span (id=15)

  - link (related - traceId=1, spanId = 00) - not a valid spanId
  - link (related - traceId=2, spanId = 20)

Is this a unique instance of a problem or are other people seeing this?

Java version - 17

```
        SpanBuilder spanBuilder =tracer.spanBuilder(spanName)
                         .setSpanKind(kind)
                         .setNoParent();
                         
        if (linkedSpans != null && !linkedSpans.isEmpty()) {
            for (Span linked:  linkedSpans) {
                log.debug("Adding link to span {} - {}", spanName, linked.getSpanContext().getSpanId());
                spanBuilder.addLink(linked.getSpanContext());
            }
        }

        io.opentelemetry.api.trace.Span oSpan = spanBuilder.startSpan();
```

Expectation: A single link within the new span

Tried: updating to the latest version of open-telemetry, logging to ensure a link was only added once.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.